# How do I restore Visual Studio settings after uninstalling Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I uninstalled Resharper after a day of use, and now I notice that some of the key bindings have changed.   for example: control-period, when hovered over a classname that is not recognized will offer to generate the appropriate usings, or will generate the full name.

I also noticed that GhostDoc no longer works.  It now says "To generalte XML comment, you must select a type or a member"

How do I restore my previous settings?  I would prefer not to have to do a full reinstallation of VS2010.

Comment: When I click control, the class name is highlighted.  is this a feature of Resharper? man, this is total crap! Resharper get out of my system!!!!! ARGHHHHHH

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which ReSharper version did you install and why have you decided to uninstall?

Comment: Yeah. They should restore VS settings back. All intellisense went away

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Have you tried Tools - Import and Export Settings - Reset all settings and Tools?

Comment: Yes, at your suggestion, I just tried this. Now, when I press the control button when hovering over a class name it offers to navigate to the definition.  This must be a resharper thing.

Comment: omg it all just decided to work again (after a rebuild). I'm going to credit this solution, even though I'm not exactly sure if that was the trick-- because this step is all I've really done so far, but it was several minutes ago.  I'm wondering if the rebuild was the trick, because closing and restarting VS didn't seem to help.

Comment: things are still a bit wonky.

Answer (score 1):

Also running `devenv /resetsettings` [will reset Visual Studio back to its original state](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/09/03/reset-the-visual-studio-environment.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the development environment of your Visual Studio with the help of "Import and Export" settings. Check this for reference:

http://www.authorcode.com/forums/topic/how-to-reset-development-environment-settings-of-your-visual-studio/